# SQL Server Setting Password value to 0x00, security concerns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

UDPATE: After seeing some of the responses, I realized there is a major error on my part. This is NOT in regards to a SQL Database User, this is a user for a web application. It is literally a table for users which is where the password hash is stored. The point of the question is specifically about the security of using 0x00 for the password hash which is used by PWDCOMPARE to prevent a web login.

User table, with a Password VARBINARY(128) NOT NULL field, which is used to store the result of PWDENCRYPT.

I need to create some users in my database that are system/bot users. Meaning, no one should ever be able to log in as those users, they're just going to be used for performing automated actions and logging. There would never be a reason to log in with that username.

Normally I would just come up with some random complex password to stick in for such a user. But today I was thinking...why can't I just use 0x00 for the password hash instead?

Are there any security concerns with using this as a password? I already tested using PWDCOMPARE with NULL, 0, '' and all come back false. So I believe I'm OK?

The only reason I'm considering this is I figured it would be an easy way to identify all users that do not have the ability to log in, I could just search for all users with password 0x00.

On the same note, if the field were nullable. What about using a NULL password hash? Same question about security.

Comment: What is your application type? Web or desktop?

Comment: So your application / bot will not be able to login also ?

Comment: It's a web application. But the users are only there so that I can log data in other tables. There will never be a need to log in with these users. It's just so I can log information under a Bot name such as in a change log or maybe notifications. Like for example, if you join a forum, you get a message from a bot saying welcome to the forum. No need to log in, because the message will be created on the SQL side.

Comment: I prefer using a boolean field in your user table, eg. Disabled. In your login process, if user is disabled, don't allow him to login.

Comment: @han yeah, that would be the preferable method. Some sort of flag. However, this is already a huge application, and even though I do have a disabled flag, it would cause all sorts of problems in many other areas. And for the time being, I want to avoid touching the schema.

Comment: So it's a web app. I never tried it, but I think it's possible to inject an ASCII zero if you use bot like Selenium. Or inject the ASCII zero using Javascript.

Comment: You can do a simple test to test it using Selenium.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. But I just tested this, PWDCOMPARE(ASCII(0x00), 0x00), and the result is still false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181516/discussion-between-han-and-chadwin).

Comment: Same for this: PWDCOMPARE(CHAR(0x00), 0x00), also results to false

Comment: Do these accounts actually haves rights to do things in the database? There's a well established pattern of "service accounts" which are logins that are only ever used by automated process. I have never ever come across any reasoning for _not_ giving these accounts passwords.

Comment: I now realize that there is an error on my part on how I worded this post. I'm not talking about SQL database users, I'm talking about using the password hash of 0x00 to prevent authentication via PWDCOMPARE for a web user for the website.

Answer (score 0):

Use the syntax

```
CREATE USER <username> WITHOUT LOGIN
```

This will create the user in the database that you can impersonate if required or just reference for your logging but is much safer than fiddling with password hashes as it is explicitly defined as never being able to be used to login.

Comment: This isn't for a SQL login, it's for a web user login.